# Adding new key values in a dictionary that was imported from an CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Sorry But I can't use pandas.

I have a sample input csv file that looks like this:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,Golf,Hotel,India,Juliett,Kilo
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2
A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,K3
A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4
A5,B5,C5,D5,E1,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5
A6,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6
A7,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7
A8,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8,J8,K8
A9,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9,H9,I9,J9,K9
```

Then my sample code looks like this:

```
import csv

fieldnames_dict = {
    'Beta': 'Beta_New',
    'Echo': 'Echo_New',
    'Foxtrot': 'Foxtrot_New_ALL',
    'Hotel': 'Hotel_New',
    'India': 'India_New',
    'Charlie': 'Charlie_New'
}

with open("book1.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv_in:
    with open("xtest_file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv_out:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                fieldnames=list(fieldnames_dict.values()))
        writer.writeheader()
        for row_in in reader:
            row_out = {new: row_in[old] for old, new in fieldnames_dict.items()}
            writer.writerow(row_out)
```

So this is what the output csv SHOULD look like:

```
Beta_New,Echo_New,Foxtrot_New_ALL,Tango,Victor,Hotel_New,India_New,Charlie_New
B1,E1,F1,T1,V1,H1,I1,C1
B2,E2,F2,T1,V1,H2,I2,C2
B3,E3,F3,T1,V1,H3,I3,C3
B4,E4,F4,T1,V1,H4,I4,C4
B5,E5,F5,T1,V1,H5,I5,C5
B6,E6,F6,T1,V1,H6,I6,C6
B7,E7,F7,T1,V1,H7,I7,C7
B8,E8,F8,T1,V1,H8,I8,C8
B9,E9,F9,T1,V1,H9,I9,C9
```

So all keys in a dictionary must be unique (so adding two empty string keys in in `fieldnames_dict` is impossible). That said, all keys in `fieldnames_dict` must already exist in input CSV file because of the row_in[old] in the dictionary comprehension `{new: row_in[old] for old, new in fieldnames_dict.items()}`. This means I will have to append/add the new keys at the end, but **how do I add the keys "Tango,Victor" and values in between "Foxtrot_New_ALL" and "Hotel_New"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you have misunderstood how `DictWriter` works.

When you specify `fieldnames=...`, `DictWriter` doesn't care *where* those field names come from, as long as it's a list of strings.

When you pass a dictionary to `writerow()`, the `DictWriter` looks at the `fieldnames` that you gave it earlier to decide which keys from that dict to select, and in what order.

So all that matters is that

1. `fieldnames` is a list of column names in the order that you want the columns in your output file.
2. any dict you pass to `writerow` contains all of the fields specified in `fieldnames`. The column order is specified by `fieldnames`, so the order the keys of this dict is irrelevant.

With this in mind, you can create a list containing your new column names that is *separate* from the dictionary that tells you how the old columns get renamed.

```
fields = ['Beta_New',
 'Echo_New',
 'Foxtrot_New_ALL',
 'Tango',
 'Victor',
 'Hotel_New',
 'India_New',
 'Charlie_New']

column_rename_dict = {
    'Beta': 'Beta_New',
    'Echo': 'Echo_New',
    'Foxtrot': 'Foxtrot_New_ALL',
    'Hotel': 'Hotel_New',
    'India': 'India_New',
    'Charlie': 'Charlie_New'
}
```

Then, you use `fields` as the `fieldnames` argument to your writer, and make sure any dicts you pass to it contain all of these field names.

```
ctr = 1

with open(...) as csv_in, open(...) as csv_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row_in in reader:
        # Convert the old field names to new field names
        row_out = {new: row_in[old] for old, new in column_rename_dict.items()}

        # Set values for extra keys
        row_out["Tango"] = f"T{ctr}"
        row_out["Victor"] = f"V{ctr}"
        ctr += 1
        
        # Write the row
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

Which gives you your new csv:

```
Beta_New,Echo_New,Foxtrot_New_ALL,Tango,Victor,Hotel_New,India_New,Charlie_New
B1,E1,F1,T1,V1,H1,I1,C1
B2,E2,F2,T2,V2,H2,I2,C2
B3,E3,F3,T3,V3,H3,I3,C3
B4,E4,F4,T4,V4,H4,I4,C4
B5,E1,F5,T5,V5,H5,I5,C5
B6,E6,F6,T6,V6,H6,I6,C6
B7,E7,F7,T7,V7,H7,I7,C7
B8,E8,F8,T8,V8,H8,I8,C8
B9,E9,F9,T9,V9,H9,I9,C9
```